# Does Spring Data JPA ignore @Fetch annotations?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have the following JPA Mapping (getters and setters out for brevity purposes, the DDL also gets generated from the code which may/may not play a role):

**Expense**

```
@Entity
public class Expense {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;


private String name;
private Long amount;
private Boolean monthly;

@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "category")
@Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
private Category category;

@ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE})
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_EMPTY)
private List<Label> labels = new ArrayList<>();
//constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

**Category**

```
@Entity
public class Category {

@Id
private String name;

//constructor, getters and setters...
}
```

**Label**

```
@Entity
public class Label {

@Id
private String name;
//constructor, getters and setters...

}
```

**Usage with JpaRepository**

So I am using a JpaRepository that looks like this:

```
public interface ExpensesRepository extends JpaRepository<Expense, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT e FROM Expense e LEFT JOIN FETCH e.category")
    List<Expense> findAllExpensesExploded();
}
```

When I use the **default findAll() method** of the JpaRepository, I get a **n+1 select problem**:

```
2017-01-03 19:35:22.665 DEBUG 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select expense0_.id as id1_1_, expense0_.amount as amount2_1_, expense0_.category_name as category5_1_, expense0_.monthly as monthly3_1_, expense0_.name as name4_1_ from expense expense0_
2017-01-03 19:35:22.673 DEBUG 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select category0_.name as name1_0_0_ from category category0_ where category0_.name=?
2017-01-03 19:35:22.674 TRACE 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Rent]
2017-01-03 19:35:22.682 DEBUG 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select category0_.name as name1_0_0_ from category category0_ where category0_.name=?
2017-01-03 19:35:22.683 TRACE 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder      : binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [Insurance]
```

However, when I use my own **findAllExpensesExploded()** method I get a single SQL query:

```
2017-01-03 19:35:22.691 DEBUG 26040 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] org.hibernate.SQL                        : select expense0_.id as id1_1_0_, category1_.name as name1_0_1_, expense0_.amount as amount2_1_0_, expense0_.category_name as category5_1_0_, expense0_.monthly as monthly3_1_0_, expense0_.name as name4_1_0_ from expense expense0_ left outer join category category1_ on expense0_.category_name=category1_.name
```

**My expectation** was for both **findAll()** and **findAllExpensesExploded()** to be executed with a **single SQL query**.

- My query worked because I seemed to have constructed it correctly
- But why does the findAll() not work with the given mapping annotations? Is it possible that Spring Data is ignoring the @Fetch annotation?
- An additional question that seems reasonable to ask is whether the default **findAll()** should only be used for simple entities? (where simple is defined as no associations).

Comment: You mean `@Fetch` annotations that are not part of the JPA spec? in which case where are they from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Default fetch mode is lazy. It's always a good practice to use `@NamedEntityGraph` and `@EntityGraph` annotations when working with Spring Data JPA.You can go through [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.entity-graph)

```
whether the default findAll() should only be used for simple entities? (where simple is defined as no associations).
```

Fetch Mode - LAZY will only fire for primary table. If in the code you call any other method that has a parent table dependency then it will fire Fetch Mode - SELECT.